# Policyd v2 Cluebringer - Quotas Message Cumulative Size

Tags: email, postfix, policyd

I have installed Policyd Cluebringer v2.0.10 from Ubuntu 12.04 packages.
I have configured it for email quotas but the quota doesn't increase when I send mails.
Here is the mail.log :

```
09:06:15 policyd postfix/smtpd[14991]: connect from unknown[192.168.64.168]
09:06:15 policyd cbpolicyd[14898]: module=Quotas, mode=update, host=192.168.64.168, helo=EDCADMV0012, from=joe@mydomain.local, to=bob@mydomain.local, reason=quota_update, policy=6, quota=3, limit=4, track=Sender:joe@mydomain.local, counter=MessageCumulativeSize, **quota=0/300000 (0.0%)**
09:06:15 policyd postfix/smtpd[14991]: 8EAEF42E74: client=unknown[192.168.64.168]
09:06:16 policyd postfix/cleanup[14995]: 8EAEF42E74: message-id=<037e01ce6d84$a42a4f70$ec7eee50$@mydomain.local>
09:06:16 policyd postfix/qmgr[13333]: 8EAEF42E74: from=<joe@mydomain.local>, **size=6792**, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
09:06:16 policyd postfix/smtp[14997]: 8EAEF42E74: to=<bob@mydomain.local>, relay=10.0.0.10[10.0.0.10]:25, delay=1.2, delays=1.1/0.03/0/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 6C82B2C7190)
09:06:16 policyd postfix/qmgr[13333]: 8EAEF42E74: removed
09:06:19 policyd postfix/smtpd[14991]: disconnect from unknown[192.168.64.168]
```

We can see that the quota doesn't change whereas the size of the email is 6792 byte.

Someone can bring me light?

Thanks!

Edit : the cluebringer.conf file :

```
[server]
protocols=<<EOT
Postfix
Bizanga
EOT

modules=<<EOT
Core
AccessControl
CheckHelo
CheckSPF
Greylisting
Quotas
EOT

user=cluebringer
group=cluebringer

pid_file=/var/run/cluebringer/cbpolicyd.pid

log_level=4
log_mail=mail@syslog:native
log_detail= policies, tracking

host=127.0.0.1
port=10031

[database]
DSN=DBI:mysql:database=policyd;host=localhost
DB_Type=mysql
DB_Host=localhost
DB_Port=3306
DB_Name=policyd
Username=root
Password=mypass

bypass_mode=tempfail

bypass_timeout=30

[AccessControl]
enable=1

[Greylisting]
enable=1    

[CheckHelo]
enable=1

[CheckSPF]
enable=1

[Quotas]
enable=1
```

Comment: Can you post the policyd config?

Comment: I added the config file /etc/cluebringer/cluebringer.conf .

Comment: What time period have you defined for the limit?

Comment: I have made a mistake! Sorry. Problem was in main.cf. I have forgotten to set 'smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031'  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a mistake in the /etc/postfix/main.cf file. 
I didn't set 'smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031'.